# A literal response to satire

Tags: english

Taking satire literally happens quite often, sometimes it's comical.

Example:

> Jim (Satirically) : "This play-area is dangerous! We should arm ourselves!"
> Jane (Literally) : "Don't worry Jim, I've got my .45."

How would you describe what Jane misunderstood about Jim's statement?  Is it possible for either Jim or Jane to know for sure if the other is speaking literally or satirically?

Append: both answers mistook the premise of the question, incorrectly assuming which speech was Satirical (of the example here which is gun owners) and the Literal response (of a gun owner). There are more examples plausible if this one is not palatable.

For example. if both were speaking openly and literally, the discussion could look like this:

> Jim : "There's no need to be armed in a playground."
>
> Jane : "Just because the people here are children, doesn't mean we won't be attacked by someone else."

But the above is moving away from the topic of the question, which is how to properly describe the misunderstanding of satire.

Comment: The question is too broad and not about linguistics as it stands. It needs to be focused on things that have to do with language rather than culture.

Comment: I think you mean "irony", not "satire".

Comment: Jane's interpretation of Jim's utterance would almost certainly depend on factors that the OP has not described.  Intonation.   Facial expressions and body-language.   Environmental context.   The phrase "(satirically)" is not a substitute for describing these factors.   The latter task might require a book-length treatment, so I am voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: No, the children in the play-ground are not actually a threat to either Jim or Jane. I also don't see how "How would you describe what Jane misunderstood about Jim's statement? Is it possible for either Jim or Jane to know for sure if the other is speaking literally or satirically?" are not questions on linguistics.

Comment: I am still not sure this is about linguistics. Moreover, there was no satire here. All I saw was sarcasm. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/satire-versus-sarcasm

Answer (score 1):

Satire is the humorous use of exaggeration or parody, to shame a party into reforming some socio-political flaw of theirs. The context involves a playground of some kind, which we culturally know is occupied by children, and we would conclude based on the mention of "arming ourselves" that the children have weapons. Satire is non-literal, but it isn't surreal. Let's assume that the children are practicing archery. For this to be satire, we need a socio-political flaw to be shaming, which could be a ballot proposal to ban any weapons in public parks (under the rationale that weapons might be used to attack people). Jim opposes the ban, and is pointing to an absurd assumption behind the proposal, that the simple presence of sporting gear that can be used as weapons will cause children to attack passers-by. We also have to assume that Jim successfully engaged in satire: if he was just being a surreal idiot (e.g. the playground was completely empty of people or animals and there is just an empty baseball diamond there), he could still say such a thing, it just wouldn't be satire.

Jane's response (and your characterization of it as a misunderstanding, as opposed to playing along with the satire) indicates that she thinks that using a .45 against children practicing archery is socially-acceptable behavior. There could be many reasons for her to have that belief, for example maybe she grew up in a civil war zone surrounded by child soldiers who actually did kill people. She did not know that Jim *actually* thinks that using a .45 against children playing is inappropriate behavior, and she actually disagrees with him.

There is no way to be absolutely sure whether a person's statement is intended literally vs. satirically. The most direct question Jane could ask is "Do you literally mean that?", but either "yes" or "no" as a response could be true or false (since people are capable of lying). She might eventually be able to garner evidence to support a suspicion one way or the other, but she couldn't be absolutely sure that he hadn't simply had a change of heart in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of **disambiguating satire or any figurative language** (and most language is figurative) is **shared knowledge of the world (and culture)**. The only way for Jim to know that Jane is speaking figuratively is that he knows she actually does not have a .45 or that she is extremely unlikely to have one. Or possibly, assuming Jane is on duty police, having a .45 is in no way relevant to the playground. You also have to start with the assumption that there is some real world context in which Jane could have interpreted Jim's statement as non-hyperbolic (e.g. the playground is a known place for drug dealing).

The assumption that there is some **universal procedure for identifying figurative language** is behind much of the unjustified British conceit that Americans don't understand irony. But this is simply caused by a lack of shared cultural (world) knowledge. Both Americans and Brits use irony/satire in about equal measure but their usage spheres do not overlap perfectly. The misunderstanding goes both ways but the stereotype developed only in one direction for other reasons.

However, this misunderstanding is not only cross-cultural. In any interpersonal relationship, the overlap in shared knowledge of the world (both general and immediate) is imperfect, thus leading to many possible confusions. Language (communication) has many **conversation repair** instruments such as 'just kidding' but that does not always prevent issues since figurative language (or which irony or satire are just one small part) often evokes very emotional responses.